# Cordova 7.1.0 : White screen after splash on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Specs :

- Cordova : 7.1.0
- iOs version : ~4.5.3

Source : [Hide splash manually](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/splashscreen/splashscreen.hide.html)

As per the Cordova docs, I've tried adding `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />` to my config.xml and calling hide manually in the apps onDeviceReady function

```
 onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent("deviceready");

    setTimeout(function() {
       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

This does not work, and it leaves my app with a spinner that is always visible.

I've also added the following to see if there might have been a network issue that was causing the white screen.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I still get a whitescreen after the splash for all devices I emulate.

---

config.xml preferences :

...

```
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

...

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="all" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
    </platform>
```

Another thing I noticed is that the app completely ignore the `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />` . No matter what value I set it to, the splashscreen is briefly shown then disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using an older version of the cordova splashcreen plugin.

I fixed it by

- removing the old plugin  : cordova plugin remove "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"
- added new plugin : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Also make sure your config.xml file is updated with :

-`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.3" /`>